# How to display total day count and set default?

Tags: android

i give total 10 days.i need result is today count 10, tomorrow reduce 1 day show count is 9,hereafter regularly reduce values up to 1.

I tried to display default the day count, i can't to get idea, anybody can do that .Pls give some ideas
how to viewed day count.

Answer (score 0):

Save "today + 10" in SharedPreferences. At every run, get the current day and subtract it from the value saved.